# Need Jquery Plugin for 2-colomns Vertical tabs

Tags: jquery

There are lot of plugins available for jquery tabs, but what I am looking for is vertical tabs.

That is, in only two columns where the first column has vertical tabs and second column has content.

Answer (score 0):

you mean like this [vertical jQueryUI tabs](http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/tabs/vertical.html)?

Comment: Yes, some thing like this, but I need more plugins to choose from.